# Bean method invocation: dynamic way

Tags: apache-camel, javabeans, spring-bean

I'd like to dynamically invoke bean method depending on some header value:

This seems doesn't work: `<to uri="bean:myBean?method=${in.header.methodName}&amp;multiParameterArray=true"/>`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just set the method name in the header called "CamelBeanMethodName" and route your message to "bean" without specifying any method.

Answer (score 1):

See this FAQ

- http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html

From Camel 2.16 its easier as you can use `<toD ..` which is the dynamic-to. In older releases you can use the recipient list EIP. Its all explained in that FAQ.